# Image not loading with a PHP variable

Tags: php, html, image, variables

```
<img width="310" height="310" src="votes/page34/page56/page78/page910/page1112/status/images/".strval(1+1).".jpg" />
```

The image 2.jpg is not showing up but when I hardcode it like :

```
<img width="310" height="310" src="votes/page34/page56/page78/page910/page1112/status/images/2.jpg" />
```

Then the image is loading frequently.

Comment: Show how you `echo` this. It doesn't make sense, you're using double quotes unescaped and concatenate using double quotes too. [It should work like this](https://3v4l.org/75VXd).

Comment: Can you please post the full line? Is this inside a `echo` function or within the plain HTML? If the latter , have you tried putting `<?php echo strval(1+1)?>` instead of your string concatenation?

Comment: <?php
$file1=1;
echo ' <html><head><body><img src="pages/votes/page34/page56/page78/page910/page1112/status/images". strval($file1+1) .".jpg"/></body></head></html>';?>

Comment: Concatenate with single quotes then: `echo '<img src="pages/votes/page34/page56/page78/page910/page1112/status/images'.strval(1+1).'.jpg"/>';`

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly put php code inside html, you must put `<?php ?>`. So your code will became like this:

```
<img width="310" height="310" src="votes/page34/page56/page78/page910/page1112/status/images/<?php echo strval(1+1);?>.jpg" />
```

Comment: @AnkitThakur then please post your full code!! Please respond (or take action) to the comments you get!

Comment: <?php $file1=1; echo ' <html><head><body><img src="pages/votes/page34/page56/page78/page910/page1112/statu‌​s/images". strval($file1+1) .".jpg"/></body></head></html>';?>

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is put your `echo` between double quotes instead of single quotes, and then escape the inline double quotes like this:

```
echo "<html><head><body><img src=\"pages/votes/page34/page56/page78/page910/page1112/statu‌​‌​s/images/". strval($file1+1) .".jpg\"/></body></head></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

see this part of your code `".strval(1+1)."` it should be `'.strval(1+1).'`

when you use `echo 'somevalue';` between single quotes and want to insert some `php code` inside it should be `'.phpvalue.'` and if you use double quotes the it should be like this `".phpvalue."`   in your case you used single so your code should be like this :

```
echo '<img width="310" height="310" src="votes/page34/page56/page78/page910/page1112/status/images/'.strval(1+1).'.jpg" />';
```

not like what you wrote :

```
echo '<img width="310" height="310" src="votes/page34/page56/page78/page910/page1112/status/images/".strval(1+1).".jpg" />';
```

So you use with echo `'` and for html parameters `"`  so when you insert `php` code separated by `'` not `"`

> update:

from your comment and your provided code you have several mistakes :

```
<?php $file1=1; 
echo ' <html><head><body>
<img  src="pages/votes/page34/page56/page78/page910/page1112/statu‌​s/images". strval($file1+1) .".jpg"/>
 </body>
 </head></html>';?>
```

you close `<head>` after `<body>` and if you wanna to get right result for your original code as it is  put this :

```
<?php 
$file1="1";
echo '<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<img width="310" height="310" src="votes/page34/page56/page78/page910/page1112/status/images/'.strval($file1+1).'.jpg" />
</body>
</html>';

?>
```